# Access column content from referenced Table using JPA / Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, persistence

Hi i am currently working on a jpa persistence layer in java.

I do have a "Customer" table that has a "country_id" column referencing a Country from the countries table. The second "Countries" Table contains two columns, the id as primary key and a "description" column.
I already created a Customer Class in java with all the annotations, but i have no clue how to access the description column from the referenced countries table.

I only need the **description as string and read only.**

Here is my current solution:
i declared the "countries" id as int in the customer class and created a seperate Country class (with required annotations and CrudRepository).
Once i need the description String i call the "findCountryById" method to get the needed Country from the Database.

This feels very wrong and i know that JPA / Hibernate does have a better solution for this. But i have no clue where to look and how to solve this puzzle in a proper way.

I do not need a Country+CountryRepository class anywhere else in my code.

So is there a better way to "directly" read the Country "description" String using the ID referenced in the Customer class ?

Comment: Instead of long text descriptions, I think it would have been much simpler and clear to show snippets of your code.

Comment: the code would only show basic "pojo" code id like to get rid of. Thats why i did not post it.

Comment: `Country` projection can be used instead of entity. You should read **Interface-Based Projections** chapter here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

Comment: I guess that should be the way to go. I'll have a look at it :)